# How do poker sites detect bots?

Tags: online, cheating

Most sites do not allow bots.

How do poker sites detect bots?

I figured they scanned memory like how HUDs are detected.

Based on an answer on another question they also detect it on the server side.

It seems to me if you put some randomness in the play which you should do anyway it would be very hard to detect.

Comment: What makes you think sites care about bots? It would be trivial to have CATCHPAs run to prevent bots. They don't. My bank makes me solve a catchpa every time I check my balance. What does that tell you?

Comment: acr also has bots but not that many

Comment: sportsbetting.ag is overran by bots. They wont do anything about it either. Every time I report a bot all they do is say they are sorry. Sorry excuse for a poker site I say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I know they track certain metrics to determine bots. Most bots are pretty damn weak but as individuals are often hard to detect. What they track tend to be the following:

1. Repeated use of identical bet-sizings (some humans have this trait
   also)
2. Repeated use of certain lines (especially uncommon lines)
3. Relentless aggression in certain spots (bots have HUD's too!)
4. Identical timing on each decision
5. Will not respond in chat
6. Might sit out at predictable times (perhaps table gets short-handed)
7. Will join a new table very quickly when there are more than a
   certain amount of players
8. Will often operate as part of a bot-ring rather than an individual

In general bots are used in conjunction with other bots, and when they're used together it becomes easier to track. They track stats and trends in general. Like for example if at micro stakes, the average player will raise 6% of the time, now imagine you have several 'players' who are opening 25% of the time. It's likely not a coincidence.

Comment: It seems like a good bot would know to vary the time to make a decision.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but good bots are not common apparently. It's mostly bad bots.

Comment: How do you know all this? None except the timing seems reliable enough to cause a ban.

Comment: I know this mainly because I work in the i-gaming industry, specially poker. This is what the security/fraud guys talk about when banning bot accounts. You're right it's not 100% reliable, but you don't have bot nets asking for accounts to be reinstated. They also don't just ban account after one bit of evidence. They can go back and see every single hand the bot has played. It becomes more reliable when you have their entire history to see patterns that frankly are just unlikely to be a human action.

Comment: What is called when they make you click to verify you are a human?

Comment: Recaptcha. I imagine poker sites use something similar to observe mouse movement.

Comment: @MelO'Hagan If they observe movement then a bot would have trouble producing random mouse movement.  It would be random but there would be a pattern.

Comment: @Paparazzi Definitely, I agree. I have seen a robotic arm beat recaptcha on a youtube video but it's no easy task. Even if there was a library out there, it would need to be adapted for poker play.

Comment: @MelO'Hagan I think you would need a bot but play manually and sometimes override the bot.  If nothing else you get on the fly equity versus their range.  Still don't do it as it is not allowed if they don't allow  bots.

Comment: Most important of all: 9. They never go on TILT ;)

Comment: @JohnDee That is just rude.  Grinch91 is a mod here and is clearly knowledgeable in poker.  He has answered enough of these type of questions that I am confident he is not making it up.

Comment: I'm rude? I assure you his information is totally fabricated. There is no such algorithm as he described. I'll tell you what, he produces a pay stub from a poker IT department, I cancel this account and never speak again on this site. He doesn't you -  apologize to me. I've been playing poker as a pro for 20 years and have been a member of the most some of the most sophisticated online cheating crews that exists. There is no such algorithm as he described because it would have banned me 1000 times over. What he listed, is what he GUESSES is true, not what is true.

Comment: Poker sites do not stop sophiticated cheating scams. When they are detected, they either hire the people invovled, pay them off, or they try to threaten them with other means. There have only been  a few actualy cases of bots that could win, and you've never heard about them, beleive me.

Comment: If you had heard of them, they would spend unlimited money to supress the issue. Because it is an existential threat to them. Losing bots are a welcome customer. The 1% of bots that win, would END the business if left alive. Yet bots exist. Go figure.

Comment: Same as casinos. Casinos don't break cheater's legs, they HIRE them. Less damage. If you can make a bot that generates $1/hr on FullTilt, you'll be WORKING there in 6 months for six figures.

Comment: @JohnDee I assure you the langue you used was rude.   Bull___ has no place here.  I am not a mod but if I was I would have hit you with a time out.  As for what you assure I do not find you a credible source.

Comment: I'm not really going to put to much here, but as an individual I have worked in the poker industry for 7 years, 5 years as a dealer in casinos around the world, 2 years as an OPs engineer in a major online card room. Granted I do not work in the industry any more, nor have I for a number of years. Perhaps the industry both online and brick and mortar have shifted since my time. I found that hard to believe though since cheating hurts their pockets and reputation.

Comment: Grinch91♦  please help here: [N00b question about calculators in online poker (or choker)](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11405/n00b-question-about-calculators-in-online-poker-or-choker)

Answer (score 1):

Some poker sites have code built into their clients that allow them to display a captcha challenge when the server requests it (which likely is manually triggered by the security team after reports from other users, or automatically if your playing behavior shows suspicious metrics as detailed by @Grinch91). And some also do track mouse movement to see if it moves in a natural fashion like a human would.

I've never been shown one personally (I don't use a bot however :P) but I've seen screenshots and also some files/symbols with very informative names while skimming through the program files and the binary code of the executables.

Captchas aren't bulletproof though, and are likely only being used as another *indication* if a particular account might be operated by a bot. Services exist (in third-world countries, where labor is cheap) where you pay a cent fee to have a captcha solved for you by a real human. They provide APIs to integrate their service into automated workflows.